# Check if Table contains a value in lua

Tags: arrays, lua, string-matching, recursive-query, lua-table

I am looking for a method to see if the value is in array (table)

The example table has 3 entries, each entry containing a table with multiple entries

Say I am checking if 'apple' is in 'data'

```
  data = {
{"alpha","bravo","charlie","delta"},
{"apple","kiwi","banana","pear"},
{"carrot","brocoli","cabage","potatoe"}
}
```

This is the code I have, a recursive query. The problem is the function breaks somewhere as it drops the positive value

```
local function hasValue(tbl, str)

local f = false

    for ind, val in pairs(tbl) do
    
            if type(val) == "table" then
        
                hasValue(val, str)

            else
                    if type(val) == "string" then
         
                        if string.gsub(val, '^%s*(.-)%s*$', '%1') == string.gsub(str, '^%s*(.-)%s*$', '%1') then 
                            f = true
                        end

                    end
            end
    end

return f end
```

Any help on this or alternative method would be greatly appreciated.

Here is the [full test file](https://ideone.com/91t0do)

Comment: Hint: Where do the results of your recursion go?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
local function hasValue( tbl, str )
    local f = false
    for i = 1, #tbl do
        if type( tbl[i] ) == "table" then
            f = hasValue( tbl[i], str )  --  return value from recursion
            if f then break end  --  if it returned true, break out of loop
        elseif tbl[i] == str then
            return true
        end
    end
    return f
end

print( hasValue( data, 'apple' ) )
print( hasValue( data, 'dog' ) )
```

true
false

Answer (score 4):

Help:

- You use `string.gsub` with a pattern that matches the whole string without trailing spaces. In your example you don't have trailing spaces at all, so it's a pointless function call and comparison. You should do direct string comparison in this case `if val == str then`.
- When you do `f = true` the function still runs until it iterates through all items, so even if it finds something it just wastes your CPU time. You should use `return true`, because it found the item, no needs to contiunue.

Solution 1:

- Best solution is to have a table lookup for all items (set-list). Create a table `lookup = {}`, and before/after you do `table.insert(a, b)` iterate `b` and add all its items into lookup table.

```lua
for k, v in ipairs(b) do
    lookup[v] = true
end
```

This puts values from `b` as keys in `lookup`, value `true` is just an indicator we have this key.
Later on if you want to know if you have this item you just do `print("Has brocoli:", lookup["brocoli"])`

Solution 2:

- This solution is **slower** but doesn't require to use additional tables. Just a fixed version of hasValue.

```lua
function hasValue(tbl, value)
    for k, v in ipairs(tbl) do -- iterate table (for sequential tables only)
        if v == value or (type(v) == "table" and hasValue(v, value)) then -- Compare value from the table directly with the value we are looking for, otherwise if the value is table, check its content for this value.
            return true -- Found in this or nested table
        end
    end
    return false -- Not found
end
```

Note: this function won't work with non-sequential arrays. It will work for your code.

Comment: You can skip the `return false` line if you want to golf it some more ;)

Comment: @DarkWiiPlayer Only if you don't need boolean specifically

Answer (score -1):

Thanks for the answer @codeflush.dev

```
local function hasValue(tbl, str)

local f = false

    for ind, val in pairs(tbl) do
    
            if type(val) == "table" then
        
                f = hasValue(val, str)

            else
                    if type(val) == "string" then
         
                        if string.gsub(val, '^%s*(.-)%s*$', '%1') == string.gsub(str, '^%s*(.-)%s*$', '%1') then 
                            f = true
                        end

                    end
            end
    end

return f end
```

Comment: This still has issue with continuation of the process, see my answer `Help -> 2 comment`