# Getting the Key of a Value in a Table and the Tables Inside of it

Tags: lua

I am making a program that searches for a value in a table. If the value isn't in that table, then it checks its child tables. It would return the FIRST found value in a table based on it's order. I cannot wrap around my head how to do this.

Here's an example of what my function would do:

```
local T = {
    ["KeyOne"] = "Val1";
    ["KeyTwo"] = "Val2";
    ["KeyThree"] = {
        ["KeyFour"] = "ValueToLookFor";
    };
    ["KeyFive"] = {
        ["KeySix"] = "ValueToLookFor"; -- Not ahead of the other index so the other index wins.
    };
}

print(SearchTable(T, "ValueToLookFor")) --> "KeyThree.KeyFour"
```

I've tried sorting the tables to the bottom of the table that is being searched and iterated through, but it didn't seem to work.
Any ideas on how I can do this?

Comment: This page might have answer for your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64717902/check-if-table-contains-a-value-in-lua/64718234#64718234

Comment: The first step is to define "order" more precisely. Lua tables are unordered, so if you care about the order of keys within one table, that will effect your algorithm. When you search subtables, do you want the first hit on a depth-first search, or do you want a strictly breadth-first search?

Comment: I just noticed the comment that says `'KeyFive'` should not be chosen. Why should `'KeyThree'` be considered ahead of `'KeyFive'`? You might need an array instead of a hash table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#! /usr/bin/env lua

local T = {
    ['KeyOne'] = 'Val1',
    ['KeyTwo'] = 'Val2',
    ['KeyThree'] = {
        ['KeyFour'] = { [1] = 'SomeOtherValue', [2] = 'ValueToLookFor' }
    },
    ['KeyFive'] = {
        ['KeySix'] = { [1] = 'Value', [2] = 'OtherValue' }
    },
}

local function locatePath( tab, value )
    local path = ''  --  placeholder
    for key, val in pairs( tab ) do

        if tab[key] == value then  --  found location
            return path ..key  --  concatenate

        elseif type( tab[key] ) == 'table' then  --  go further down the rabbit hole
            local found = locatePath( tab[key], value )

            if found ~= '' then  --  found relevant path
                return path ..key ..'.' ..found  --  concatenate location

            end  --  found
        end  --  recursion
    end  --  pairs
    return path
end  --  function

print( locatePath( T, 'ValueToLookFor' ) )
```

`KeyThree.KeyFour.2`

Answer (score 0):

You can use recursive search, but this will **not guarantee the order of keys**, as lua tables are hash tables.

```html
<script src="https://github.com/fengari-lua/fengari-web/releases/download/v0.1.4/fengari-web.js"></script>
<script type='application/lua'>

function SearchTable(t, value, prefix)
  for k,v in pairs(t) do
    if type(v) == 'table' then
      local res = SearchTable(v, value, prefix and (prefix .. '.' .. k) or k)
      if res then
        return res
      end
    end
    if v == value then
      return prefix and (prefix .. '.' .. k) or k
    end
  end
end

local T = {
    ["KeyOne"] = "Val1";
    ["KeyTwo"] = "Val2";
    ["KeyThree"] = {
        ["KeyFour"] = "ValueToLookFor";
    };
    ["KeyFive"] = {
        ["KeySix"] = "ValueToLookFor"; -- Not ahead of the other index so the other index wins.
    };
}

print(SearchTable(T, "ValueToLookFor"))

</script>
```

If you want ordered search (for exmple by name) you need extra code at function begining, there is an example in official documentation: https://www.lua.org/pil/19.3.html